# How to remove strings from a json file

Tags: reactjs, django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xj6dJ.png)

I am trying to convert it into a json file but the thing is that the single quotations marks are in between the two brackets instead of being outside them so I cannot use JSON.parse() to convert it to a json so I don't know how to get rid of those single quotations at the start and end of the data.

Comment: please remove the link to the picture of text and add the actual text so that it can be copied and tested

Comment: Can this problem be rephrased as "How to convert an array of strings where each string represents a JSON object to an array of real objects?"

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to chop off the brackets:

```
    const reg = [/\[\'/, /\']+$/];
    const string = "['YOUR JSON']";
    const str = string.replace(reg[0], "");
    const newStr = str.replace(reg[1], "");
    console.log(newStr);
```

I hope that will solve your problem